# Tsql table variable to Oracle PLSql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle12c

I am working on TSql to Plsql conversion.
There are several table variables declared and used in tsql, like

```
DECLARE @table_var table( id_ int ......)
WHILE ...
begin
insert into @table_var select ...
...
select * from @table_var..
```

I think in oracle global temporary table can be used, but the data will be maximum 10k rows.

How efficient global temporary tables in this case?
Is there any other way other than `global temporary table` and `table types` in Oracle to convert similar sql query?

Oracle version: `oracle11g` or `oracle12c`

Comment: It's rare to really need a temporary table in Oracle, and as you've discovered it only support global temporary tables, not local ones. The real question to ask yourself is whether you really need to hold the data in your own structure at all - do you need to do anything with `table_var` other than select from it later, which you could do by selecting/joining to your initial select instead? You can use schema-level table types instead but they might be overkill too. The snippet is too small and vague to really tell what you need.

Comment: There are same area in the code that the `table_var` cannot be substituted by `select` or `join`. I didn't understand `schema-level table types instead but they might be overkill too`...... `table type` or `temp table` for a data size of `10k rows`?

Comment: It depends *why* it can't be substitued, what you are doing with that variable, how many times you use it, how expensive the query that populates it is, etc. Your question is too abstract at the moment really, except for equally abstract answers *8-)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your size of the data and task that you want to achieve-- you can use

1. Pl/sql record/table and bulk processing
2. hold data in to cursor and loop through it
3. if you want kind of query update -- you can use in-line view
   (preserving primary key)

Comment: `table type` or `temp table` for a data size of 10k rows?